# SSIS package: How to insert/update data into a Sql server's table by calling a web service in a ssis package?

Tags: web-services, sql-server-2008, ssis

Is there any way to call a web service in a ssis package in order to insert some data into a table within SQL Server? How? any sample or guidance please?

Comment: Why would you call a web service, instead of just connecting to SQL Server directly? If you can explain that, someone may have a suggestion.

Comment: It's not possible connection to SQL SERVER directly. They gave us a web service instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by your question, you are referring to using a web service as a destination for a data flow? I inherited a series of packages that integrate with our MS CRM site. As designed, these packages are a horrible fit for the SSIS paradigm but that's my burden to bear...

These packages generally fit the form of Source (OLE DB or Flat File) fed to a Script Task (destination). I don't know that providing all the code of a particular task would be enlightening. It's simply invokes the web service for each row sent into it. [RBAR](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) is not what SSIS or set based languages are made for but you can certainly do it.

- The Script transformation will have a web reference (ours is named CrmSdk) to the service.
- Declare an instance of the service as a member of `ScriptMain`.
- Instantiate that service in your script, passing credentials as needed. Most likely in your `PreExecute` method
- Make calls to the web service in your `Input0_ProcessInputRow` method using the Row.Column1 notation. Do be aware of nulls and how the web service handles them. Our code uses `service.CompanyName = Row.CompanyName_IsNull ? string.Empty : Row.CompanyName;`

If your intention is to use a web service at the Control Flow level, be aware that the default Task has a hard coded 5 minute timeout. Not sure if that's still the case, but in the 2005 package I was dealing with, we had to use a straight Script Task to communicate with our webservice (it was cleansing millions of rows of address data in batch fashion) to bypass the timeout issue.  [Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to timeout property